# Finding share of event type in a given day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table below (do not worry about the PK)

```
CREATE TABLE event(
user_id int,
session_id int,
event_type varchar(60),
event_time datetime
)

insert into event(user_id,session_id,event_type,event_time)
values
(1,101,'Home Page','2020/01/01'),
(1,102,'Search','2020/01/01'),
(1,103,'View Item','2020/01/01'), 
(1,104,'Checkout','2020/01/01'), 
(2,105,'Home Page','2020/01/02'), 
(2,106,'Search','2020/01/02'), 
(3,107,'Home Page','2020/01/03'), 
(4,108,'Home Page','2020/01/03'), 
(5,109,'Home Page','2020/01/04'), 
(5,110,'Search','2020/01/04');
```

And I am trying to find the share of event type in a given day. Based on the sample data I provided, below is the number of event types in each day.

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00.0   Home Page   1
2020-01-01 00:00:00.0   Search      1
2020-01-01 00:00:00.0   View Item   1
2020-01-01 00:00:00.0   Checkout    1
2020-01-02 00:00:00.0   Home Page   1
2020-01-02 00:00:00.0   Search      1
2020-01-03 00:00:00.0   Home Page   2
2020-01-04 00:00:00.0   Home Page   1
2020-01-04 00:00:00.0   Search      1
```

I want to get the percentage of each event type in a day;

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00.0   Home Page   1    25%
2020-01-01 00:00:00.0   Search      1    25%
2020-01-01 00:00:00.0   View Item   1    25%
2020-01-01 00:00:00.0   Checkout    1    25%
2020-01-02 00:00:00.0   Home Page   1    50%
2020-01-02 00:00:00.0   Search      1    50%
2020-01-03 00:00:00.0   Home Page   2    100%
2020-01-04 00:00:00.0   Home Page   1    50%
2020-01-04 00:00:00.0   Search      1    50%
```

Can you please help me modify my query?

```
SELECT
     event_time 
    ,Event_type
    ,COUNT(user_id) as event_count
FROM Event
GROUP BY event_time,event_type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT event_time, Event_type
       COUNT(*) as event_count,
       COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY event_time) as ratio
FROM Event
GROUP BY event_time, event_type
```

Comment: Great! How do I filter this to find last 30 days? I need to get today's date and calculate last 30 days and filter. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Eren . . . That is just a `where` clause:  `WHERE event_time >= curdate() - interval 30 day`.